Unable to open a website from Excel 2016 Power query editor from AWS
Trying to access the below link
"https://www.nseindia.com/api/corp-info?symbol=IRB&corpType=financialResult&market=equities" from Excel 2016 power query editor (From AWS cloud).
but getting error:
DataSource.Error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
I've tried opening the same link from edge with cloud itself, it successfully opened the link.
Am I missing any thing.
I've tried using the same browser cookies from excel, below is the code
let
    stock="IRB",
    Source = Web.Contents("https://www.nseindia.com/api/corp-info?symbol=" & stock & "&corpType=financialResult&market=equities", [Headers=[#"accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate", #"accept-language"="en-US,en", #"user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36", Cookie=""& cookie() &""]])
in
    Source

cookie format = "nsit=nUwoEEy235D3tHLxmcBGqU0q;nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTcxMjAyMzcwNiwiZXhwIjoxNzEyMDMwOTA2fQ.pbTC6qbTuTnLCAceh6OGTHO5slgpCRVL9KzAvyYZ3YU"

After troubleshooting it seems, NSE website blocked connections from the Cloud providers, and hence it's not connecting from the cloud, but it's working from the local system.

You're not referencing the cookie properly. One way to do it:
let
    cookie = "nsit=nUwoEEy235D3tHLxmcBGqU0q;nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTcxMjAyMzcwNiwiZXhwIjoxNzEyMDMwOTA2fQ.pbTC6qbTuTnLCAceh6OGTHO5slgpCRVL9KzAvyYZ3YU",
    stock="IRB",
    Source = Web.Contents("https://www.nseindia.com/api/corp-info?symbol=" & stock & "&corpType=financialResult&market=equities", [Headers=[#"accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate", #"accept-language"="en-US,en", #"user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36", Cookie=""&cookie&""]])
in
    Source

This gets me to an authentication prompt, which means that the web call is successful.

Thanks a lot for the response and your valuable time, I have a cookie function, that collects the information from a file, and hence I mentioned it like that. Also, I tried your code, the thing is it works in the local computer but not in the AWS cloud. However, I am getting the below error message: DataSource.Error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Details:
https://www.nseindia.com/api/corp-info?symbol=IRB&corpType=financialResult&market=equities. But the same link I can able to open in the edge browser in the cloud server.

I am not sure, but do I need to tweak any settings of excel 2016 power query editor, as the same link works in edge but not in editor  in the cloud*
